# Unmarshal an ISO-8859-1 XML input in Go

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, go

When your XML input isn't encoded in UTF-8, the `Unmarshal` function of the xml package seems to require a `CharsetReader`.

Where do you find such a thing ?

Comment: The best answer to this common problem changes when go changes. I already gave twice the "accept" mark to another answer in order to avoid people using an obsolete solution.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Updated answer for 2015 & beyond:**

```
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
)
reader := bytes.NewReader(theXml)
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel
err = decoder.Decode(&parsed)
```

Answer (score 22):

Expanding on @anschel-schaffer-cohen suggestion and @mjibson's comment,
using the [go-charset](http://code.google.com/p/go-charset/) package as mentioned above allows you to use these three lines

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReader
err = decoder.Decode(&parsed)
```

to achieve the required result. just remember to let `charset` know where its data files are by calling

```
charset.CharsetDir = ".../src/code.google.com/p/go-charset/datafiles"
```

at some point when the app starts up.

**EDIT**

Instead of the above, `charset.CharsetDir =` etc. it's more sensible to just import the data files. they are treated as an embedded resource:

```
import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-charset/charset"
    _ "code.google.com/p/go-charset/data"
    ...
)
```

`go install` will just do its thing, this also avoids the deployment headache (where/how do I get data files relative to the executing app?).

using import with an underscore just calls the package's `init()` func which loads the required stuff into memory.

Comment: Have an upvote but it's disappointing to have to have external resources for such a simple operation than this conversion.

Comment: Agreed. Probably just 'still early days for go'.. I'm pretty happy with "go get" though as it makes the whole thing pretty close to painless

Comment: @mschuett In 2011, peterSo's answer was the best one and thus I accepted it. You should have a look at all answers before starting to code. Anyway, I'll accept this one now to avoid confusion.

Comment: @dystroy sorry, I posted this before i read the comment up top and just forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a sample Go program which uses a CharsetReader function to convert XML input from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. The program prints the test file XML comments.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "utf8"
    "xml"
)

type CharsetISO88591er struct {
    r   io.ByteReader
    buf *bytes.Buffer
}

func NewCharsetISO88591(r io.Reader) *CharsetISO88591er {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, utf8.UTFMax))
    return &CharsetISO88591er{r.(io.ByteReader), buf}
}

func (cs *CharsetISO88591er) ReadByte() (b byte, err os.Error) {
    // http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT
    // Date: 1999 July 27; Last modified: 27-Feb-2001 05:08
    if cs.buf.Len() <= 0 {
        r, err := cs.r.ReadByte()
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        if r < utf8.RuneSelf {
            return r, nil
        }
        cs.buf.WriteRune(int(r))
    }
    return cs.buf.ReadByte()
}

func (cs *CharsetISO88591er) Read(p []byte) (int, os.Error) {
    // Use ReadByte method.
    return 0, os.EINVAL
}

func isCharset(charset string, names []string) bool {
    charset = strings.ToLower(charset)
    for _, n := range names {
        if charset == strings.ToLower(n) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func IsCharsetISO88591(charset string) bool {
    // http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets
    // (last updated 2010-11-04)
    names := []string{
        // Name
        "ISO_8859-1:1987",
        // Alias (preferred MIME name)
        "ISO-8859-1",
        // Aliases
        "iso-ir-100",
        "ISO_8859-1",
        "latin1",
        "l1",
        "IBM819",
        "CP819",
        "csISOLatin1",
    }
    return isCharset(charset, names)
}

func IsCharsetUTF8(charset string) bool {
    names := []string{
        "UTF-8",
        // Default
        "",
    }
    return isCharset(charset, names)
}

func CharsetReader(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, os.Error) {
    switch {
    case IsCharsetUTF8(charset):
        return input, nil
    case IsCharsetISO88591(charset):
        return NewCharsetISO88591(input), nil
    }
    return nil, os.NewError("CharsetReader: unexpected charset: " + charset)
}

func main() {
    // Print the XML comments from the test file, which should
    // contain most of the printable ISO-8859-1 characters.
    r, err := os.Open("ISO88591.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer r.Close()
    fmt.Println("file:", r.Name())
    p := xml.NewParser(r)
    p.CharsetReader = CharsetReader
    for t, err := p.Token(); t != nil && err == nil; t, err = p.Token() {
        switch t := t.(type) {
        case xml.ProcInst:
            fmt.Println(t.Target, string(t.Inst))
        case xml.Comment:
            fmt.Println(string([]byte(t)))
        }
    }
}
```

To unmarshal XML with `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` from an `io.Reader` `r` into a structure `result`, while using the `CharsetReader` function from the program to translate from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`, write:

```
p := xml.NewParser(r)
p.CharsetReader = CharsetReader
err := p.Unmarshal(&result, nil)
```

Comment: @dystroy: To protect yourself and your users, establish an audit trail by including a clear acknowledgement of the source (Stack Overflow) and the author (peterSO) of the code. Include a full link to this question or my answer. Include a full link to my Stack Overflow user page. I'm glad you found the code useful.

Comment: Yikes.  Is this still the best answer?  Everyone who wants to read ISO-8859 has to jump through these hoops?

Comment: this should be packaged into a library so that other people can just drop it in to the xml parser.

Comment: This answer is a little outdated. It uses many packages that have since been restructured and will not work in go 1.3. I have an answer below that will work with newer versions of go and will also handle many different charsets that are not handled by this answer. Although it is worth understanding how this is implemented.

Comment: @peterSO Your answer was the best one when I asked in 2011 and was helpful to me and other developers. But we're now in 2015 and developers are still coming to this question, looking for a solution. I've been asked many times to accept the solution which, today, is the best one, and I'll do it now. Sorry for having to unaccept your answer.

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be an external library which handles this: [`go-charset`](http://code.google.com/p/go-charset/). I haven't tried it myself; does it work for you?

Comment: I'll try, thanks (for now I just made a trivial charsetreader working only for the ASCII reduced set and I'll try a complete translation as soon as I've resolved my other issues).

But I'm surprised that go seems to consider that the world is made of UTF-8 today.

Comment: I think it's more a matter of considering UTF-8 to be the best *internal* representation for Unicode, and not having finished the libraries yet.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: do not use this, use the go-charset answer.

Here's an updated version of @peterSO's code that works with go1:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

type CharsetISO88591er struct {
    r   io.ByteReader
    buf *bytes.Buffer
}

func NewCharsetISO88591(r io.Reader) *CharsetISO88591er {
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    return &CharsetISO88591er{r.(io.ByteReader), &buf}
}

func (cs *CharsetISO88591er) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for _ = range p {
        if r, err := cs.r.ReadByte(); err != nil {
            break
        } else {
            cs.buf.WriteRune(rune(r))
        }
    }
    return cs.buf.Read(p)
}

func isCharset(charset string, names []string) bool {
    charset = strings.ToLower(charset)
    for _, n := range names {
        if charset == strings.ToLower(n) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func IsCharsetISO88591(charset string) bool {
    // http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets
    // (last updated 2010-11-04)
    names := []string{
        // Name
        "ISO_8859-1:1987",
        // Alias (preferred MIME name)
        "ISO-8859-1",
        // Aliases
        "iso-ir-100",
        "ISO_8859-1",
        "latin1",
        "l1",
        "IBM819",
        "CP819",
        "csISOLatin1",
    }
    return isCharset(charset, names)
}

func CharsetReader(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    if IsCharsetISO88591(charset) {
        return NewCharsetISO88591(input), nil
    }
    return input, nil
}
```

Called with:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
d.CharsetReader = CharsetReader
err := d.Decode(&dst)
```

Comment: Using go-charset is actually the best answer, so I'd rather peterSO's answer remain wrong to point people in that direction. (I only discovered go-charset after porting his code.)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any provided in the go distribution at the moment, or anywhere else I can find.  Not surprising as that hook is [less than a month old](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-dev/browse_thread/thread/4e7cd6400186fa78/33c58399405a68f8?lnk=raot) at the time of writing.

Since a CharsetReader is defined as `CharsetReader func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, os.Error)`, you could make your own.
There's one example in the [tests](http://golang.org/src/pkg/xml/xml_test.go?h=CharsetReader#L214), but that might not be exactly useful to you.

Comment: I saw the exemple in the tests, it's not exactly useful, indeed. In fact I failed to understand how this CharsetReader should work.