# Go iso-8859-1 encoding support in go.text

Tags: encoding, go

I use go.text in my project
https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/encoding

I do not understand why it is missing `iso-8859-1`?

I know I can easily transcode it `byte -> rune -> utf8`
[Unmarshal an ISO-8859-1 XML input in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002619/unmarshal-an-iso-8859-1-xml-input-in-go)

But I wonder if there is some encoding in go.text that is `iso-8859-1` but named differently. I know it has following names.

```
    ISO_8859-1:1987
    ISO-8859-1
    iso-ir-100
    ISO_8859-1
    latin1
    l1
    IBM819
    CP819
    csISOLatin1
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/go-charset/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Windows1252` in place of `iso-8859-1`.

> This character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1, but differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

> ISO-8859-1 assigns several control codes in this range. Windows-1252 has several characters, punctuation, arithmetic and business symbols assigned to these code points.

There is a chart with the differences here:

http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html