# Golang XML encoding

Tags: xml, parsing, go

How to parse XML with Windows 1250 encoding in Go language?

- Code below working fine with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in XML file.
- Code is not working with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>` in XML file.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// Regions comment
type Regions struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"CNUMNUTS"`
    RegionList []Region `xml:"CNUMNUTS_ROW"`
}

// Region comment
type Region struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"CNUMNUTS_ROW"`
    Nazevnuts string   `xml:"NAZEVNUTS"`
    Numnuts   string   `xml:"NUMNUTS"`
    Nuts      string   `xml:"NUTS"`
    Kodcis    string   `xml:"KODCIS"`
    Chodnota  string   `xml:"CHODNOTA"`
}

func main() {

    xmlFile, _ := os.Open("cnumnuts.xml")
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    var regions Regions

    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &regions)

}
```

I'm using Go 1.13.7 on Windows 64bit

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate: [Unmarshal an ISO-8859-1 XML input in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002619/unmarshal-an-iso-8859-1-xml-input-in-go)

Comment: [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)  is not the same as [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2) (for central Europe). And ISO-8859-2 is not exactly same as [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250).

Comment: Irrelevant. The solution is independent of the actual charset.

Comment: Right Peter, thank you. I received weird result with `charset` before, because VSCode saved my xml in UTF-8 anyway. When I used original xml file, it works fine.